# What exactly is has_many and how does it work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I was looking at associations in ruby and was wondering how they work from a syntactic standpoint.

looking at:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to              :portfolio
  has_one                 :project_manager
  has_many                :milestones
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

My understanding is that has_many for example is a method that is called with the parameter ":milestones". But how can this be? How can there be a method call in the class body but not inside of another method or function?

Not sure if you get what I mean. But hopefully someone can explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's object model is very unlike more classical languages object oriented languages like C++ or java where classes are like blueprints carved on a stone tablet.

In Ruby classes are class objects that are mutable. Another way to put this is classes are just objects that work as factories to create instances of itself.

You can execute any code you want in the class definition:

```
class World
  puts "Hello #{name}"
end
```

As its evaluted from top to bottom.

This is used extensivly for [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). For example you declare setters and getters by using `attr_accessor`:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(age:)
    @age = age
  end
end
```

Which modifies the class by adding an `age` and `age=` method. which looks something like this:

```
class Person

  def age
    @age
  end

  def age=(value)
    @age = value
  end

  def initialize(age:)
    @age = age
  end
end
```

Rails associations work them same way - just way more complex. `belongs_to :portfolio` creates a setter and getter and [reflection objects](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/MacroReflection.html) that keep track of what sort of association it is.

Comment: btw, it's `attr_accessor`, not `attribute_accessor`.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Ah, missed the other occurence

Answer (score 4):

> But how can this be? How can there be a method call in the class body but not inside of another method or function?

Class definition is just code, like any other. When class file is loaded, its body is evaluated, top to bottom. This includes calling methods like `has_many` (this one comes from the depths of `ActiveRecord::Base`). Or any other methods.

```
class Foo
  puts "Loading class #{name}"
end

# >> Loading class Foo
```

Note that this `puts` is executed by merely loading the file with the class. You don't even have to do `f = Foo.new` or anything like that.